# SQL - Multiple Rows Into One

Tags: sql, sql-server

*First of all, I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726013/sql-multiple-rows-into-one), and my question is different - albeit slightly. Also I have tried the approach and tried to modify it to work for me, but no dice.*

**Question:**

From a result of a couple of queries I get the following result:

```
ID   |  NAME  |   DESCID  |   TALL   |   GOODLOOKING   |   FAT
_______________________________________________________________
1    |  John  |      1    |  '1.8m'  |       Null      |   Null
1    |  John  |      2    |   Null   |      'Yes'      |   Null
1    |  John  |      3    |   Null   |       Null      |  '84kg'
1    |  John  |      4    |   Null   |       Null      |  '85kg'
```

*Note: Just some dummy data BTW.*

I need the output to be the following:

```
ID   |  NAME  |   TALL   |   GOODLOOKING   |       FAT
__________________________________________________________
1    |  John  |  '1.8m'  |       'Yes'     |   '84kg|85kg'
```

If this is not possible I would appreciate knowing that, so feel free to tell me.

Any help SQL legends?

Comment: so only concatenation in `fat` column? what if `Goodlooking` had 2 `not null` `distinct` values?

Comment: Concatenation in any of the columns following descid. Thanks for asking

Comment: Group_concat, is that SQL Server, or just MySQL?

Comment: Sql server. As in tag.

Comment: You could also take a look at recursive CTEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like `Group_Concat` in SQL Server which can be used directly. You can use `FOR XML` in a correlated query

```
SELECT ID,NAME,
STUFF((SELECT '|'+TALL        FROM Tbl1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.NAME = t1.NAME ORDER BY t2.descid FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') as tall,
STUFF((SELECT '|'+GOODLOOKING FROM Tbl1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.NAME = t1.NAME ORDER BY t2.descid FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') as GOODLOOKING,
STUFF((SELECT '|'+FAT         FROM Tbl1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.NAME = t1.NAME ORDER BY t2.descid FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') as FAT
FROM Tbl1 t1
GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/838e4/1)

Comment: Looks good. I've upvoted for effort, will mark as answer after test. Thanks

Comment: Okay well This works. The solution however is too slow. Is that just a product of this type of work? Because this is slower than brunt looping in c# - considerably.

Comment: Yes, This would be slow as sql needs to read the table 4 times.

Comment: @Terrance00: Since you are saying that the non-aggregated row set is the result of a couple of queries, you might try and see if the technique suggested here can be combined with any of those queries – who knows, it might perform better when applied to original datasets.